# Objects retain info from previous loop iteration

Tags: python

I have a class called `run_c` which is being used to initialize and execute the run of a kinematics simulation. I assign default values to the attributes of `run_c`, such as `x`, before `run_c.__init__()` is executed. All `__init__()` is doing is extracting user-input values, aggregated into a dictionary, and assigning them to corresponding attributes in `run_c` if they exists. For example...

```
import vars.Defaults as dft
class run_c:

   ...
   dt     = dft.dt
   x      = dft.x0
   states = [ [], [], [], [] ]
   ...

   def __init__(self, input):
      for key in input.keys():
         if hasattr(self, key): setattr(self, key, input[key])
      ...
      self.execute()
```

`run_c.states` is a list of lists that is being used to record the values of `run_c` attributes as they change with timesteps. Later, within `run_c.execute()`, I am storing `x` values in `states[1]`, incrementing the timestep `dt`, and updating `x` using velocity and timestep. It's pretty simple stuff, right?...

Here's where the problem begins, though. The first time that the instance of `run_c` is created, initialized, and executed, it runs perfectly. However, I am operating this simulation by creating, initializing, and executing multiple runs based off of list read from a JSON file. As such, in the driver module...

```
from Run import run_c
def main():
   ...
   for runEntry in runList:
      currRun = run_c(runEntry)
      ...
   ...
```

What happens is that all the values that were stored in `run_c.states` do not get wiped after each iteration of the loop. I thought that new instances of `run_c` are being created every time I run the loop so as to execute `__init__()` fresh with new information. Why are the data values, such as old values for `x`, being retained after the end of each loop?

Update: When I add in a line of code to reset the values of `states` back to empty lists within `__init__()`, the problem goes away. But this shouldn't be a necessary step in what I want to do...should it?

Comment: How often are you creating a *new, empty* list for `states`? Once: while defining the class. The list object is not getting reset for each new instance.

Comment: So is the list `states` only being assigned and never used? When I mention `self.states`, is that a completely separate entity? Or is it more similar to global variables than to class variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dt`, `x`, and `states` are defined as *class* variables, not *instance* variables. Every instance of that class that you make will share them. If you need them to be initialized each time you generate a new instance, that's exactly what `__init__()` is for:

```
class run_c:

   def __init__(self, input):
      ...
      self.dt     = dft.dt
      self.x      = dft.x0
      self.states = [ [], [], [], [] ]
      ...

      for key in input.keys():
         if hasattr(self, key): setattr(self, key, input[key])
      ...
      self.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answer: you can initialize these variables in the `__new__` method.

```
class A:
    val = 1

    def __new__(cls, v):
        t = super().__new__(cls)
        t.val = v
        return t

    def __init__(self, v):
        val = v

a, b = A(1), A(2)

print(a.val, b.val)
```

If you remove the `__new__` method, the output'd be `1 1` and otherwise `1 2`.

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner, no, nobody'd get mired in class hierarchies as `super` doesn't care about it. No, the semantics of these 'magic' methods is not obscure: you write them once, and when you use your classes, you don't see them at all. This answer shows how _not to_ move the variables' definitions into `__init__` and achieve the OP's goal, that's it.